# How to install Ubuntu Remix Mini on a VM?

Tags: live-cd

My VM boots into live-CD of Ubuntu Remix Mini.

How do I install it on the VM's HDD?

Comment: @MadMike You can add an answer based on the comment and You should. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## It isn't meant to be installed

The Ubuntu Remix Mini was build to create your own custom live-CD. As such it doesn't come with a installer. But ..

## You can still install it manually

As per the Source: [FAQ #35](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mini-remix/+faq/35) Entry of Ubuntu Mini Remix. There is an guide from Nicolás Pierini.

Unfortunately it isn't entirely complete and requires some Linux know how. This guide requires a working Ubuntu Grub installation from where it copies the `/boot/grub`-tree. Also the part about installing the grub MBR is missing. There is no explanation how to partition your drives and it isn't discussed how this would work in an  EFI environment.

Anyway. I've transcribed this guide from Nicolás Pierini and added the part about how to get the UUID. Maybe someone wants to extend it and make it complete.

1. Mount the filesystem to `/mnt`

   ```
   $ sudo mount -t squashfs -o loop filesystem.squashfs /mnt
   ```
2. Copy the whole squashfs to the hard drive. In this example mounted in `/media/hdd`. Check were yours is mounted and change all the commands below accordingly!

   ```
   $ sudo cp -R /mnt/* /media/hdd
   ```
3. Copy the grub directory from a fresh installation of Ubuntu. This needs to be the same version as the ubuntu-mini-remix. In this example mounted in `/media/newUbuntu`. Change accordingly!

   ```
   $ sudo cp -R /media/newUbuntu/boot/grub/* /media/hdd/boot/grub
   ```
4. Find the UUID of the hdd disk.

   ```
   $ mount | grep /media/hdd
   /dev/sda1 on /media/hdd type ext4 (rw,noatime,barrier=0,user_xattr)
   ```

   The device path of the mounted /medai/hdds in this example is `/dev/sda1`. So do this to find the UUID.

   ```
   $ sudo blkid /dev/sda1
   /dev/sda1: LABEL="root" UUID="a4645210-c1f9-4b25-91dd-aaa5051fed7a" TYPE="ext4"
   ```
5. Open grub.cfg and replace the UUIDs with the UUID of the hdd disk

   ```
   $ gksu gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg
   ```
6. Erase the root password and let users login without password

   ```
   $ gksu gedit /media/hdd/etc/shadow
   ```

   Replace `root:*:14892:0:99999:7:::` with `root::14892:0:99999:7:::`

   ```
   $ gksu gedit /etc/pam.d/common-auth
   ```

   Replace `nullok_secure` with `nullok`
7. Finished. Now you can boot the PC from the Ubuntu Mini Remix on your hdd instead of the live-CD. Add a new users, or login as root.